# Racket Programing - creating a function that takes two arguments and returns a function

Tags: racket

Write a Racket function named compare that takes two arguments, functions f and g, each of which takes a single integer argument.

compare returns a function of one argument, an integer n. The returned function computes the value f(n) > g(n). For example:

```
>(define double (lambda (n) (* n 2))) 
>(define square (lambda (n) (* n n)))
>(define 2n+1 (lambda (n) (add 1 (double n)))

>((compare square double) 2)    ; is (2*2) > (2*2)?
#f
>((compare square double) 5)    ; is (5*5) > (5*2)?
#t
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
(define compare
  (lambda (f g)
    (lambda (int)
      (lambda (int-two)
          (>= (f g))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

> Write a Racket function named compare...

```
(define compare ...
```

> ...that takes two arguments, functions f and g, each of which takes a single integer argument.

```
(define compare
  (lambda (f g)
    ...
```

> ...compare returns a function of one argument, an integer n.

```
(define compare
  (lambda (f g)
    (lambda (n)
      ...
```

> ...The returned function computes the value f(n) > g(n).

```
(define compare
  (lambda (f g)
    (lambda (n)
      (> (f n) (g n)))))
```

Comment: alternatively (and more succinctly), `(define (compare f g) ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `call` your functions `f` or `g` at some points.

You also need to provide the function `double` in `f` and `square` in `g` in order to met your condition `>=`.

You can try the following code in the `Racket` interpreter:

```
(define double (lambda (n) (* n 2))) 
(define square (lambda (n) (* n n)))

(define compare
  (lambda (f g)
    (lambda (int)
       (printf "F:~A G:~A Condition:~A~%" (f int) (g int) (>= (f int) (g int)))
       (>= (f int) (g int)))))

(let ((compare-function (compare double square)))
  (printf "Result 1: ~A~%" (compare-function 2))
  (printf "Result 2: ~A~%" (compare-function 5)))
```

Which should provide the following results:

```
F:4 G:4 Condition:#t
Result 1: #t
F:10 G:25 Condition:#f
Result 2: #f
```